# Duplicate input unix stream to multiple TCP clients (using socat)

Tags: sockets, socat

I have a syslog server which writes to a unix stream `/tmp/syslog.socket`. 
I need to duplicate this stream to multiple TCP clients. Is there a way to achieve this using socat?

Comment: But syslog is normally `udp`?

Comment: Yes. For my setup it receives data from other machines using UDP and writes them to a unix stream socket.

Comment: @CalinDon does my proposed answer work for you to accept?

Answer (score 3):

I think I just accomplished this, especially the duplicating part, with the help of [Some Helpful socat Commands](http://technostuff.blogspot.com/2008/10/some-useful-socat-commands.html).

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:4444,reuseaddr,fork SYSTEM:"tail -f ~/.tail-error-logs/*",pty
```

`fork` is important on the left side, `pty` is important on the right side.

What didn't work, was netcat style:

```
tail -f ~/.tail-error-logs/* | socat STDIO TCP-LISTEN:4444,fork,reuseaddr
```

It had the effect of output alternating between multiple attached clients, which is also documented [on above website](http://technostuff.blogspot.com/2008/10/some-useful-socat-commands.html).

Comment: Why is `pty` important? When I leave it out the alternation issue stops and all data is sent to all clients.

Answer (score 1):

syslogd has a facility for redistributing the logs via udp, see the man page for syslogd, ie

http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl8_syslogd.htm

I believe that syslog-ng also supports tcp sockets for log redistrubution as well as udp

http://www.syslog.org/syslog-ng/v2/

I would guess that you don't need a hack with socat?

Comment: As far as I know, syslog can only write to a destination and read from a destination (can be only one end of the link); it cannot listen for a connection and then write to that connection.